Overlapping emmissions with Euclidean decay
I have a number of emission sources (roads) with varying emission values (noise). For the sake of simplicity, let's say the sources were 3 points. The emitting noise decreases by the inverse distance to the source. To calculate the noise arriving at each pixel, I have to do the following for each source:

Extract the noise level at source i (call this val)
Calculate the distance to source i (call this dist)
Value at each pixel: val/dist

I'm working in R with terra, so these steps look as follows:
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(terra))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(raster)) # needed for some operations
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(sf))

# produce dummy data, 3 points with locations x,y and initial value z
points <- data.frame(
  x = c(30,50,60),
  y = c(40,20,30),
  z = c(500,1000,10),
  n = c("A", "B","C")
) |> st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y"))

# create a template raster 
template <- rast(res = 1, extent = c(0,100,0,100))

# calculate the the value for each source (constitutionally costly)
rasts <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(points)), \(i){
  val <- points[i,]$z
  dist <- points[i,] |> 
    rasterize(template, field = "z") |> 
    distance()
  dist[dist == 0] <- 1
  1/dist*val
}) |> 
  rast() |> 
  max() 

cols <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")
plot(rasts,col = cols,  legend = FALSE, main = "Emission Value (correct but costly)")
text(points,labels = points$n)


Since I have a very high number of sources, it's not feasible to calculate the emissions for each source individually.
I only want the max (or sum) value per pixel, I initially thought I could calculate the noise level per pixel by the following steps:

Calculate distance to the nearest source
Calculate 1/distance (decayval)
Allocate every pixel with the noise value of the nearest source (euclid_alloc)
Multiply decayval with euclid_alloc to get the noise level for each pixel.

However, this approach is flawed, since this doesn't take overlapping emissions into account. I illustrate this issue with the code below:
# convert the extent of the template raster to an sf object
bb_sf <- template |> 
  ext() |> 
  vect() |> 
  as("Spatial") |> 
  st_as_sfc()

# rasterize the points
points_ras <- rasterize(points, template, field = "z")

# calculate the distance to the nearest point to get 
# the decay value (1/dist)
dist <- distance(points_ras)
decayval <- 1/dist

# calculate Euclidean Allocation using voronoi polygons
euclid_alloc <- st_union(points) |>
  st_voronoi(envelope = bb_sf) |> 
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON") |> 
  st_as_sf() |> 
  st_join(points) |> 
  rasterize(template, field = "z")

# calculate the new values based on euclidean allocation 
# and the decayval
decay <- decayval*euclid_alloc


par(mfrow = c(1,3))
plot(euclid_alloc,legend = FALSE, main = "Euclidean Allocation")
plot(points, add = TRUE, col = "black")

plot(decayval,legend = FALSE, main = "Decay Value")

plot(decay,col = cols, legend = FALSE, main = "Emission Value (flawed)")
plot(points, add = TRUE, col = "black",pch = "x")


As you can see, the point on the lower right disrupts the emissions from the lower left point. Is there any way to solve this issue without having to calculate the emissions per source?

Is this happening because the right-most source (call it C) is quieter (lower z value) than the southernmost source (call it B) and so even points close to C might get their loudest noise from B? I think this might be some sort of weighted voronoi problem...

Thinking again, and assuming my intuition on the problem is right, its not a voronoi problem because its non-local - a really loud source a long way away could be the largest value at a source even with several other sources between. There might be some speedups to be had by starting with the loudest source and then working out the distance where nothing can be louder than it then you know all locations in that distance must get max noise from that. Exclude those pixels and that source and repeat... Maybe...

Yes I think you understood the problem quite well. I was thinking maybe some sort of cost-distance function could be helpful, but I might be wrong.

I have a solution: The focal function of the terra package provides the possibility to pass a custom, weighted matrix as the window. This is a pretty awesome feature of terra, most software only allow an equally weighted window or specific filters (such as Gauss, Sobel etc).
You can create a matrix with weights corresponding to the inverse distance to the window centre. You can then pass this matrix together with a summary function (like max or sum) to focal to get the summarised value per cell. Here is the implementation in code:
# Specify a focal radius (this is a downside, see below)
radius <- 50
# Create a Focal Window of type "Circle"
foc_circle <- focalMat(template, radius, type = "circle") |> rast()

# Make a copy of this Window and set all values to NA, except for the center
foc_dist <- foc_circle
values(foc_dist) <- NA
foc_dist[radius+1, radius+1] <- 1

# Calculate the distance to the center using the "distance" function and set
# all values outside the circle to NA. Then inverse the values and reset the
# center from inf to 1. Convert the raster back into a matrix
foc_dist <- distance(foc_dist)
foc_dist[foc_circle == 0] <- NA
foc_invdist <- 1/foc_dist
foc_invdist[radius+1, radius+1] <- 1
foc_invdist_mat <- matrix(foc_invdist)
dim(foc_invdist_mat) <- dim(foc_invdist)[1:2]

# Use this matrix to calculate the value per cell. Fill NA values with 0
point_focal <- focal(points_ras, foc_invdist_mat, max, na.rm = TRUE, fillvalue = 0)
point_focal[is.na(point_focal)] <- 0

par(mfrow = c(1,2))

plot(rasts,col = cols, legend = FALSE, range = c(0,1000), main = "Original / correct values")
plot(points, pch = "x", add = TRUE)

plot(point_focal,col = cols, legend = FALSE, range = c(0,1000), main = "focal Method")
plot(points, pch = "x", add = TRUE)




Note:

Since focal is a costly operation, this approach is only faster if the number of sources is high
This approach limits the search window to a specific radius (e.g. 50), values outside this radius are NA. E.g.: The top right corner (100, 100) is 94 units away from point B (50 20), which has a value of 1000. The value for this cell should be 1/94*1000 = 10.6, in the focal approach it's NA, because 94 > 50.
This approach is very flexible in...

...how you weigh your distances, you could also use a Gauss method or inverse distance to power (e.g. 1/dist^2).
...how you summarise your values, you could also use mean or median



